# Convert String To HTML in EJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

```
<section class="hide card-section">
    <% for(var i = posts.length-1; i>=0; i--){ %>
        <div class="card">

            <div class="image">
                <img src=<%= posts[i].image %>>
            </div>

            <div class="card-content">
                <h1><%= posts[i].header %></h1>
                <%
                const months = ["Ocak", "Şubat", "Mart", "Nisan", "Mayıs", "Haziran", "Temmuz", "Ağustos", "Eylül", "Ekim", "Kasım", "Aralık"];
                const result = posts[i].date.getDay() + " " + months[posts[i].date.getMonth()] + " " + posts[i].date.getFullYear();
                %>
                <div class="dateauthor"><p class="keywords"><%= result %></p></div>
                <span class="description">
                    <%=posts[i].content // -> I want to convert this string to html %> 
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    <%}%>
</section>
```

I have to convert that 'posts[i].content' to HTML because its looks like this

[image]

As you can see, its treating like a string. I cant try document.createElement because document return me undefined because of EJS view engine (i guess)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
<%- posts[i].content %>
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to use `<%- %>`, you can find it in the docs.

[image]